# Can i get RSpec to generate specs with expect syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When generating specs with :

```
rails g controller Home index
```

A spec is generated with the older object.should syntax

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe HomeController do   
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end  
end
```

**Is it possible to configure the generator to use the expect syntax instead?**

Desired output:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe HomeController do

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'index'
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end

end
```

in config/application.rb:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec, fixture: true
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: 'spec/factories'
  g.view_specs false
  g.stylesheets = false
  g.javascripts = false
end
```

Comment: This has been fixed by this [commit](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/commit/652a77d24874d15feebce473dfb8de19d12708a) and is no longer relevant, yay!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  I haven't done it for my controller, but I've done it for models.  Should be the same process.  For my model I created `lib/templates/rspec/model/model_spec.rb` with the following contents:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe <%= class_name %> do

  let(:<%= singular_name %>) { FactoryGirl.create(:<%= singular_name %>) }

  it "should be valid from the factory" do
    expect(<%= singular_name %>).to be_valid
  end

end
```

If you do it, post your solution.  It bugs me too, so wouldn't mind taking your version :-)

Comment: I dug through [the gem repository](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) and it seems that there is only one set of templates. So the answer would be no. But this is a really nice workaround so I´m going to accept it.

Comment: Nice solution. If I am reading your template right, you should switch your `let` to a `subject`. Why can't you use `singular_name` in the expect block?

Comment: @Shepmaster - I've never liked `subject`.  And yeah, I should be able to use `singular_name`.  I imagine I was just putting it together and it worked and I left it alone :)  I'll update the code.  That's better.

Comment: That's a shame that you don't like subject. I find that it clarifies what the test is actually acting upon - `let` is for dependencies, `subject` is for the interesting thing. Also, it enables the short-form tests: `it { should be_valid }`

Comment: True.  Some days I consider it, but just never gotten into it.  Bit too magical I guess.

Answer (score 0):

available in release 3.0.0.rc1. `gem 'rspec', '~> 3.0.0.rc1'`